# PHP Form not sending to email address on same server

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts, mx-record

I'm using a very simple PHP form on my websites, but the form will not send the message to any email sitting on my server I.E

pixology.net/contact.php

Will not send to brad@pixology.net
But will send to bradhouston@gmail.com

Here is the code, any ideas?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "brad@tpdesign.co.uk";
    $email_subject = "TP Design Contact Form";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- REDIRECTED PAGE ONCE CONTACT FORM IS SUCCESFULL -->

<?php require_once('thankyou.php'); ?>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Are you sure that the email sent to @pixology.com does not get filtered as spam?
Also, do you see any exception messages if you remove the @ in front of the mail() command when sending to @pixology.com?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the \r\n in the headers with just \n as noted in the Mail docs "If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some poor quality Unix mail transfer agents replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822." - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @Re0sless has a good point as well. I would recommend using a framework to send your emails just to make sure the headers are correct for all outgoing email messages using php.
Have a look at www.swiftmailer.org as an example.

Comment: Henkealg & Re0sless I just tried both of these, none worked. Brad

Comment: Is there a super simple framework? A my knowledge f PHP is very minimal.

Comment: Do you host email on the same server or use an external service (e.g. Google Apps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that you host your email elsewhere than your server, you need to make sure that it is set to resolve to a remote exchanger.

[See this article](https://knowledgebase.servint.net/questions/286/What+is+the+difference+between+Local,+Backup,+and+Remote+Mail+Exchanger+in+cPanel?%20%20) for information on how to do it in WHM/cPanel.

If you don't have access (e.g. you're on a shared environment), then contact your webhost and they should be able to arrange it for you.

Comment: The email is hosted on the server.